# how to parallelize with unpredictable work?

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency

Brief recap: The main structure of the program is a unbalanced tree(not binary), that i create on the fly, and as soon as i create a node i check if it's the solution (then the program can terminate) or not. The tree is not balanced, so i can have a branch with N nodes, a branch with 1 node, and a branch  with n^2 nodes. But the creation and check of a node is very little, so i can't assign just 1 node per thread, otherwise the overhead will overwhelm the execution time. What can i do?

Hi, i have done this brute force sudoku solver and i would like to parallelize it, but i'm not sure what would be the best approch, if a pipeline, a farm, a map-reduce and so on. I will post you the sequential code so it will be easier to parallelize. The main structure of the program is a tree, beeing a brute force approch, each possibility is a node with it's own sudokuMatrix.
The logic of the program follows this steps:
-It takes a sudoku matrix in input or generate it.
-It find the first empty cell, then calculate which number can be inserted there.(respecting the sudoku rules)
-It generate a node for each possibility(and it add them to the parent node as "child"), each node has a matrix with the corresponding number added in the sudokuMatrix.
-It continue like that iterating recursively until a solution is found.

! The algorithm must be brute force, it is an uneditable requirement, but of course i can choose another brute force approch, even if i would like to keep that to don't change things too much.

Now the approche i tried to parallelize it was to just split the work at the beginning in n parts (where n = number of threads choosen) of equal work more or less, and to give them to threads with a farm.
Since the recursion will create a very big unbalanced tree, i just make the first 1-2 steps sequentially, until i have at least a number of childs (imagine it as the first or second level of a very big tree) equal to the number of workers, then i split them in equal parts, and i give the sub-trees to the workers (the sub-trees are of course unbalanced, but since it is created on the fly, i can't balance it more precisely).

The problem i face is that i can't explore all the recursive tree, and the split in equal parts and give to the threads, because i generate the tree on the fly and as soon as i generate a solution matrix, the  all programs terminate because i found a solution. On the other hand i can't solve each level of the tree splitting the works to all the threads because the works of each level is very little and it will cause a very big overhead.

What could be a better approch to parallelize THIS program? (i know brute approch isn't efficient and so on, but again, i can't change it, more precisely it must be a brute force approch, so anyway the brute force will be there even if a little more efficiently).

I'ill post you just the sequential solution(it's the full code so you can reproduce it if you want):
! Note that on the recursive call (solveSudoku) i added a little sleep to simulate a bit more of work, otherwise the function is too fast and the overhead would overwhelm it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

#define UNASSIGNED 0
#define N 9
#define ERROR_PAIR std::make_pair(-1,-1)

using namespace std;
atomic<bool> solutionFound{false};

//declaration for new tree node
struct Node 
{ 
    array<unsigned char, N*N> grid;
    vector<Node *>child; 
}; 
   
 // Utility function to create a new tree node 
Node *newNode(const array<unsigned char, N*N> &newGrid) 
{ 
    Node *temp = new Node; 
    temp->grid = newGrid;
    return temp; 
} 
  

void printGrid(const array<unsigned char, N*N> &grid) 
{ 
    for (int row = 0; row < N; row++) {
        if(row==3 || row == 6){
            cout << "---------------------" << endl;
        } 
        for (int col = 0; col < N; col++){
            if(col==3 || col==6){
                cout << "| ";
            }
            cout << (int)grid[row+col*N] << " "; 
             
        }
        cout << endl;
    } 
} 

bool canInsert(const int &val,const int &row_, const int &col_,const array<unsigned char, N*N> &grid){
    //check column
    for(int row = 0; row < N; row ++){
        if (grid[row+col_*N] == val) return false;
    }
    //check row
    for(int col = 0;col < N; col ++){
        if (grid[row_+col*N] == val) return false;
    }
    //check box
    for(int row = 0; row < N; row++){
        for(int col = 0; col < N; col++){
            if (row/3 == row_/3 && col/3 == col_/3){ //they are in the same square 3x3
                if((grid[row+col*N] == val)) return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

//vector<vector<int>> gridTest(9, vector<int>(9,0)); il vettore deve essere inizializzato, cosi.
//n = how many numbers you want to initialize the matrix with
void generateMatrix(const int &seed,const int &n,array<unsigned char, N*N> &grid){ 
    srand(seed);
    int i = 0;
    while ( i < n){
        int row = rand()%9;
        int col = rand()%9;
        int val = rand()%9+1;
        if(grid[row+col*N]== UNASSIGNED && canInsert(val,row,col,grid)){
        grid[row+col*N] = val;
        i++;
        }
    }
    return;
}

bool isSafe(const array<unsigned char, N*N> &grid) //check if the sudoku is solved
{ 
    char row_[9][N+1] = {0};
    char column_[9][N+1] = {0};
    char box[3][3][N+1] = {0};
    for (int row = 0; row < N; row++) { 
        for (int col = 0; col < N; col++) { 
            // mark the element in row column and box 
            row_[row][grid[row+col*N]] += 1; 
            column_[col][grid[row+col*N]] += 1; 
            box[row / 3][col / 3][grid[row+col*N]] += 1; 
  
            // if an element is already 
            // present in the hashmap 
            if ( 
                box[row / 3][col / 3][grid[row+col*N]] > 1 
                || column_[col][grid[row+col*N]] > 1 
                || row_[row][grid[row+col*N]] > 1) 
                return false; 
        } 
    }
    return true; 
} 


pair<int,int> findCell(const array<unsigned char, N*N> &grid){
  for (int i=0;i<N;i++){
      for(int j=0;j<N;j++){
          if (grid[i+j*N] ==UNASSIGNED){
              return make_pair(i,j);
          }
      }
  }
  return ERROR_PAIR;
}

void addChoices (list<array<unsigned char, N*N>> &choices,Node &node){
    while(!choices.empty()){
            node.child.push_back(newNode(choices.front()));
            choices.pop_front();
        }
    return;
}

list<array<unsigned char, N*N>> getChoices(const int &row,const int &col,const array<unsigned char, N*N> &grid){
    list<array<unsigned char, N*N>> choices;
    for(int i=1;i<10;i++){
        if (canInsert(i,row,col,grid)) { 
            array<unsigned char, N*N> tmpGrid = grid;
            tmpGrid[row+col*N] = i;
            choices.push_back(move(tmpGrid));
        } 
    }
    return choices;
}

void solveSudoku(vector<Node *> &nodes){
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
    if(solutionFound) {return;};
    for (Node *&n : nodes) {
    if (findCell(n->grid) != ERROR_PAIR){
        pair<int,int> freeCell = findCell(n->grid);
        list<array<unsigned char, N*N>> choices = getChoices(freeCell.first,freeCell.second,n->grid);
        if(choices.empty()) { 
        return ;
        }
        addChoices(choices,*n);
        solveSudoku(n->child);
    } else if(isSafe(n->grid)){
            solutionFound = true;
            printGrid(n->grid);
            cout << "That's the first solution found !" << endl;
            return;
    } else {
        cout << "No solution found ! " << endl;
        return;
    }
    }
}



//TO DO: fai inserire quando chiami il programma se vuole generare una matrice, true o false, e se si quanti numeri iniziali dare.
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    array<unsigned char, N*N> grid = 
                                      {3, 0, 6, 5, 0, 8, 4, 0, 0, 
                                       5, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                       0, 8, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 
                                       0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 8, 0, 
                                       9, 0, 0, 8, 6, 3, 0, 0, 5, 
                                       0, 5, 0, 0, 9, 0, 6, 0, 0, 
                                       1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 5, 0, 
                                       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 4, 
                                       0, 0, 5, 2, 0, 6, 3, 0, 0};
    
    Node *root = newNode(grid);
    vector<Node *> vec;
    vec.push_back(root);
    solveSudoku(vec);

     chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
     chrono::duration<double> time_span = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::duration<double>>(t2 - t1);
    cout << "end" << endl;
        std::cout << "It took me " << time_span.count() << " seconds." << endl;
    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**The Simple Solution: OpenMp and schedule(dynamic)**

If you're able to transform your code into a large loop, you can use
`#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)` to parallelize your whole loop.
I can't come up with an example on your specific case, so I've choosen [ray tracing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_tracing_(graphics)):

```cpp
void paint(char* picture, int width, int height) {
# pragma omp parallel for collapse(2) schedule(dynamic)
    for(int i=0; i < width; ++i) {
        for(int j=0; j < height; ++j) {
           picture[i*width+j] = calc_pixel(i, j);
        }
    }

}
```

In ray tracing, you can calculate each pixel on it's own without needing to know all the other pixels. But calculating a pixel can take varying amounts of time, so you'd have unbalanced work if you just gave each thread the same number of pixels.

Note that in order to do schedule(dynamic), you need a central work distribution where a thread will ask for a piece of work, access a shared (synchronized) queue or similar to get one. In this case, the work for one pixel will be too small compared to this overhead.

To fix that, we can add a second parameter to schedule(dynamic): the number of iterations that shall be seen as "one unit of work". Let's say we want 200 pixel to be seen as "one unit of work", we can simply state schedule(dynamic, 200). It'll create more load-imbalance, but less synchronization overhead.

**Back to your example**

Let's say we can't use OpenMp. OpenMp might be disallowed, you might not be comfortable using it or you simply can't use a for-loop for your problem.
We can still learn from this approach and build it for your problem by hand.

The Idea behind schedule(dynamic) is quite simple: There's a queue of work, and whenever someone finished his own work, he asks for a new piece of work.
We can implement that for your problem. Just make sure your shared data-structure is protected by a mutex.

What's your piece of work? It's a (partially solved) Sudoku. Some might be unsolvable, some might be solvable. As soon as you've found a solution, your done.

Let's look at the work method that's going to be called for each thread:

```cpp
#define WORKSIZE 20
void work() {
    while(!finished) {
        int* field;
        field = getWork();
        std::vector<int*> orphans;
        for (int i=0; i < WORKSIZE; ++i) {
            auto pos = findCell(field);
            auto options = getChoices(pos.first, pos.second,field);
            if (options.empty()) {
                delete[] field;
                if (orphans.empty()) {
                    // get new work
                    break;
                } else {
                    field = orphans.pop_back();
                    continue;
                }
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < options.size() - 1; ++j) {
                // store all your other options in orphans as you are not going to try them right now
                int* newfield = new int[N*N];
                std::copy(field, field+N*N, newfield);
                newfield[pos.first*N+pos.second] = options[j];
                orphans.push_back(newfield);
            }
            // work on the last option
            field[pos.first*N+pos.second] = options[options.size()-1];
        }
        // We've now finished our item of work.
        // it's time to share our remaining work with the centralized queue:
        orphans.push_back(field);
        publishWork(orphans);
    }

}
```

Now you just need to implement a thread-safe `getWork` and `publishWork`, play with WORKSIZE and you should be fine.

Note that this isn't the only option how to parallelize unbalanced work without openmp. I just like it.

Comment: the problem is that i don't have a queue of work, is like the pixel computation but you dont get the entire image at the beginning, instead you discover some pieces each time you compute one of them. And i think that computing one piece, then you discover 4 new pieces, you add them to the work queue, and re-syncronize all the threads is not worth, i think.

Comment: Please take another look at my example. It's inefficient to synchronize for one pixel, it's inefficient to synchronize for one guess. But you can increase the number of guesses done locally by playing with WORKSIZE. 200 guesses before accessing the global queue? Fine, just set WORKSIZE to 200 instead of 20.

Comment: Please note that your example is way too simple for anything like that. It only takes up to 900 guesses and takes about a millisecond on my pc. If you want to see any speedup you need a more difficult example.

Comment: i know but that's the homework :), for this reason im using the sleep just to simulate an harder work.